# Does it make sense to have a model with only static methods?

Tags: architecture, asp.net-mvc-2

I have an ASP.NET MVC 2 project that I'm working on and I'm wondering where I should place some of my code.

I currently have a UsersModel which consists of a bunch of static methods that operate against my data context.

These methods include such things as: `UserExistsInDatabase`, `UserIsRegisteredForActivity`, `GetUserIdFromFacebookId` etc etc.

Should these methods be inside a UsersModel class or would they be more suited to a user helper class outside of the models context?

Cheers for any pointers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use static methods. Abstract them in a repository:

```
public interface IUsersRepository
{
    bool UserExistsInDatabase(User user);
    bool UserIsRegisteredForActivity(User user);
    ...
}
```

then implement against some data store:

```
public class UsersRepository : IUsersRepository
{
    ...
}
```

and finally give your controller an instance of this repository so that it can work with users:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IUsersRepository _repository;
    public HomeController(IUsersRepository repository)
    {
        // the repository is injected into the controller by the DI framework
        _repository = repository;
    }

    // ... some action methods that will use the repository
}
```

Comment: While I agree with Darin completely, I'd suggest that the reason you'd want to do this is so that the UserRepository can be mocked/substituted in your tests. Mocking/substituting classes with static methods is very difficult.

Comment: Excellent answer (again today) Darin. Cheers. Colin, thanks for the extra info. This will certainly make my unit testing much easier - Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I think we should avoid static methods as it will have issue in mocking. These methods are better suited for a UserRespository/UserService class.

Answer (score 0):

sound like a class "User" with the properties/functions:
* ExistsInDatabase,
* IsRegisteredForActivity,
* GetIdFromFacebookId

Answer (score 0):

Either of those options are OK.  Alternatively, you could define them as extension methods and attach them to the user class directly.

HTH.